# VIM is not currently reading .vimrc

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vim

Recentely I have installed VIM 8.0 at my Ubuntu 18.10. After the installation, I follow this steps `https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim` to prepare my plugin manager of VIM.

There is a directory `~/.vim` and a subdirectory `~/.vim/bundle` where I suppose to save the plugins for VIM. Beside that, there are the .vimrc file (`~/.vim`) and vundle.vim (`~/.vim/bundle`).

I did the follow setup to `.vimrc`

```
set nocompatible              " be iMproved, required
filetype off                  " required
set number

" set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()
" alternatively, pass a path where Vundle should install plugins
"call vundle#begin('~/some/path/here')

" let Vundle manage Vundle, required
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'

" The following are examples of different formats supported.
" Keep Plugin commands between vundle#begin/end.
" plugin on GitHub repo
Plugin 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
" plugin from http://vim-scripts.org/vim/scripts.html
" Plugin 'L9'
" Git plugin not hosted on GitHub
Plugin 'git://git.wincent.com/command-t.git'
" git repos on your local machine (i.e. when working on your own plugin)
Plugin 'file:///home/gmarik/path/to/plugin'
" The sparkup vim script is in a subdirectory of this repo called vim.
" Pass the path to set the runtimepath properly.
Plugin 'rstacruz/sparkup', {'rtp': 'vim/'}
" Install L9 and avoid a Naming conflict if you've already installed a
" different version somewhere else.
" Plugin 'ascenator/L9', {'name': 'newL9'}

" All of your Plugins must be added before the following line
call vundle#end()            " required
filetype plugin indent on    " required
" To ignore plugin indent changes, instead use:
"filetype plugin on
"
" Brief help
" :PluginList       - lists configured plugins
" :PluginInstall    - installs plugins; append `!` to update or just :PluginUpdate
" :PluginSearch foo - searches for foo; append `!` to refresh local cache
" :PluginClean      - confirms removal of unused plugins; append `!` to auto-approve removal
"
" see :h vundle for more details or wiki for FAQ
" Put your non-Plugin stuff after this line
```

When I tried to install the Plugin via `:PlugInstall` or `:PluginInstall` vim tells me that there are not those commands. I noticied that the basics setup as `set number` are not working as well.

After a lot of research I check that when I check the `:scriptnames`:

```
  1: /usr/share/vim/vimrc
  2: /usr/share/vim/vim80/debian.vim
  3: /usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/syntax.vim
  4: /usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/synload.vim
  5: /usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/syncolor.vim
  6: /usr/share/vim/vim80/filetype.vim
  7: ~/.vimrc
  8: /usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/nosyntax.vim
  9: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/getscriptPlugin.vim
 10: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/gzip.vim
 11: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/logiPat.vim
 12: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/manpager.vim
 13: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/matchparen.vim
 14: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim
 15: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/rrhelper.vim
 16: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/spellfile.vim
 17: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/tarPlugin.vim
 18: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/tohtml.vim
 19: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/vimballPlugin.vim
 20: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/zipPlugin.vim
 21: /usr/share/vim/vim80/scripts.vim
 22: /usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/vim.vim
 23: /usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/lua.vim
 24: /usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/perl.vim
 25: /usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/pod.vim
 26: /usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/ruby.vim
 27: /usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/python.vim
```

What appear to me that vim is checking `.vimrc`.

I tried, also, `:set runtimepath`:

`runtimepath=~/.vim,/var/lib/vim/addons,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles,/usr/share/vim/vim80,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after,/var/lib/vim/addons/after,~/.vim/after`

Where again is showing me that there is the path to `~/.vim`.

I suspect that may be some problem in the `vundle.vim` (`~/.vim/bundle`) or something else.

Anybody can help me?

Comment: Where exactly is your vimrc? You're saying it's `~/.vim`, but that's a directory.

Comment: @melpomeneMy vimrc file is inside the ~/vim directory. I just typed `vim .vimrc` and wrote the global setup.

Comment: Vim doesn't read `~/.vim/.vimrc`. It only reads `~/.vimrc` (as your `:scriptnames` output shows).

Comment: Vim reads `$HOME/.vimrc` or `$HOME/.vim/vimrc`.  See `:help vimrc`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you are placing your .vimrc configuration into the wrong directory (`~/.vim/`).

Please try placing the .vimrc file directly into your home directory.

I was able to successfully run the `:PluginInstall` command after running the following commands:

```
vim ~/.vimrc          # (Insert vim configuration)
mkdir -p ~/.vim/bundle/
cd ~/.vim/bundle/
git clone https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim
```

Comment: Did you mean to create another directory ~/.vimrc and inside the directory put my .vimrc file?

Comment: I've updated my answer; it was quite misleading. The .vimrc file should be placed directly into your home directory (without any subdirectory).

Comment: I spent many hours trying to resolve the problem! Thank you very much